# Trying to add a second IP adress to a network adapter but getting Resource {0} not found on Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface

Tags: azure, powershell, nic, azure-rm

I am trying to add a second IP address on a network adapter on a Azure Virtual machine scale set using the AzureRm cmdlet using Powershell.

My code looks like this:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$vnetname = "confvnet"
$loc = "West Europe"
$backendSubnetName = "conf-jira-interlink"
$backendSubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -AddressPrefix "10.0.4.0/24"
echo "backendSubnetConfig: "$backendSubnetConfig

$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter"
echo "vnet: "$vnet

Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet -AddressPrefix "10.0.4.0/24" | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
$subnetId = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id
echo "subnetId: "$subnetId

$ipCfg = New-AzureRmVmssIPConfig -Name 'eth1' -SubnetId $subnetId -PrivateIPAddressVersion 'IPv4' -Primary $false
echo "ipCfg: "$ipCfg

$backendSubnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet
echo "backendSubnet: "$backendSubnet

$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter -VMScaleSetName confcluster
echo "vmss: "$vmss

Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -Name $backendSubnet -Primary $false -IPConfiguration $ipCfg -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter -VMScaleSetName confcluster
$Nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -VirtualMachineScaleSetName 'confcluster'
echo "Nic: "$Nic

$ipconfig_interlink = New-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name "ipconfig-conf-jira-interlink" -Subnet $backendSubnetConfig -PrivateIpAddress "10.0.4.20"
Add-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name $ipconfig_interlink.Name -Subnet $backendSubnetConfig -NetworkInterface $Nic
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name $ipconfig_interlink.Name -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.4.20 -Subnet $backendSubnetConfig -NetworkInterface $Nic
$Nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -VirtualMachineScaleSetName 'confcluster'
echo "Nic: "$Nic

Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $Nic
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -VMScaleSetName "confcluster" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

But I'm getting the error

> Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface : Resource '{0}' not found In
>   X:\JIRA_Confluence_Migration\PowerShell\network-interfaces-azure-same-vnet.ps1:67
>   Zeichen:1
>   + Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $Nic
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.SetAzureNetworkInterfaceCommand
>   on Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What's the output of that line: `echo "Nic: "$Nic`?

Comment: The output is on https://www.paste.org/99234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, you just need to change the command like below:

```
$Nic | Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface
```

Then it will work without the error.

But as I see in your script, you just get the network interface then set it without any change. If so, the command does not affect anything. You can take a look at the example of the command [Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermnetworkinterface?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples).

**Update**

According to another test, there is a point should be focused on. Azure VM Scale Set instances are not the same as the VM. You can not find the network interfaces of the instances in the group which the VMSS in. All the instances are created from the same configuration, so do the network interfaces. As the error shows, the resource does not found.

You can take a look at the question that [How do I specify a range of private IP addresses to use for static private IP address allocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq#how-do-i-specify-a-range-of-private-ip-addresses-to-use-for-static-private-ip-address-allocation). So I think that it's a wrong way that you want to set the NIC of the instance through the command `Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface`.

Just as your previous question, you can set the network configuration of the VMSS, it's the right way for VMSS.

Comment: I have changed the code to
`$Nic | Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface`

and I have also added the lines

`$Nic.IpConfigurations[1].PrivateIpAddress = "10.0.4.20"
$Nic.IpConfigurations[1].PrivateIpAllocationMethod = "Static"`

but I'm still getting the same error `Resource '{0}' not found`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried the Az module, but I'm getting the same error.

My code looks like

https://www.paste.org/99311

I'm getting the error message `Set-AzNetworkInterface : Resource '{0}' not found`

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong with the Az module?

Comment: @RonnyForberger I update the answer, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's looking for the identifier of the NIC itself, and not an object. Try:

```
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $Nic.Id
```

Comment: Hi Dicky Moore,
no doesn't work. It expects the type PSNetworkInterface.

Comment: Could it be that you're getting back an array of objects, even if there's only one object in the array? In which case, -NetworkInterface $Nic[0] ?

Comment: Dicky Moore, I am not exactly sure what I am getting back. But when I change the call to -NetworkInterface $Nic[0], I still get the same error.